# Values of Cord are getting smaller in Rotation Matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, rotation

I´m teaching my self to use c++ with OpenGL. I want to rotate Objekts by changing the corresponding points.
Like already the headline said, I´m struggling. My objekts are shirking, the numbers are getting smaller and smaller, each time im  calling my function.
I´m pretty sure my matrix is right.
I´m trying to rotate around the y-Achse. I tryd to implement a rotation around the z-aches, same Problem.

Do you see what im miss here?
I´m pretty new to c++, I´m only learning  java at school.
Thx for your Time.

```
void drehen (float gradY) {
    //point a
    a.setX(a.getX() * cos(gradY) + a.getZ() * sin(gradY));
    a.setZ(a.getZ() * cos(gradY) + a.getX() * -sin(gradY));
    
    //point b
    b.setX(b.getX() * cos(gradY) + b.getZ() * sin(gradY));
    b.setZ(b.getZ() * cos(gradY) + b.getX() * -sin(gradY));

    //point c
    c.setX(c.getX() * cos(gradY) + c.getZ() * sin(gradY));
    c.setZ(c.getZ() * cos(gradY) + c.getX() * -sin(gradY));

    //point s
    s.setX(s.getX() * cos(gradY) + s.getZ() * sin(gradY));
    s.setZ(s.getZ() * cos(gradY) + s.getX() * -sin(gradY));


    std::cout << "x:" << a.getX() << "\tz: " << a.getZ() << "\n";
    init();
}
```

Comment: `a.setX` modifies `a.x` and `a.setZ` uses the already modified value instead of the original

Comment: ... common mistake.

Comment: ahhhh, now I did understand you thx.

Comment: Also, I would avoid calling this function repeatedly with small values for gradY, since you will accumulate rounding errors by chaining a large number of small incremental rotations.. I would keep a copy of the original, non-rotated coordinates as your starting point and call ``drehen()`` with increasing values of ``gradY``.